# MVC saving a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an export to csv option but am having trouble getting the file dialog to pop up (I used [this](http://rachelappel.com/upload-and-download-files-using-asp-net-mvc/) tutorial). When the csv button is clicked, the form is triggered with export option set to true so the controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FieldQueryResult(QueryInput input, bool exportCsv)
{
     //input gets processed to create 'sb' which is the csv string
     if (exportCsv)
        {
            var fileString = sb.ToString();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[] { };
            bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileString);
            return new FileContentResult(bytes, "text/csv");               
        }
}
```

However it just steps through this code without popping up the file dialog.  What am I doing wrong please?  I thought maybe it's because  I'm returning a `FileContentResult` from `ActionResult`, but from what I've read they're supposed to be interchangeable.

Comment: AFAIK, the file "save" dialog depends on browser settings in client side - what do you really want? `FileContentResult` apparently inherited from `ActionResult`, hence it's legal for file return purpose.

Comment: Try to change "text/csv" to  System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet

Comment: S. Petrosv, I tried that, but it made no difference.

Comment: Tetsuya, I just want the file save as dialog to pop up so the user can save the csv file.

Comment: As I remember this is only works for supported files formats like pdf, and if browser supports it, it will open the pdf as a "site". You could try write direcly to the stream. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500737/exporting-data-into-csv-mvc4

Comment: I believe I have discovered the source of the issue, which is that my link is in fact a form submit.  When I just use an @Html.actionlink , the file dialog does indeed pop up.  Now I just need to figure out how to get my form data to the FileResult action.

Answer (score 1):

phew, well it was quite a journey through many attempts at a solution that didn't work, but I finally got it, through some ajax and a session variable, so I thought I'd post it here in case it helps anyone else.

The crux of the problem is that for FileResult to work, it needs to be called from an Actionlink, but I was creating my csv string from a form and it seems you can't get the file dialog to display after posting a form .  What I did was put the form in an ajax post, then in the post method add the csv string to a session object and then on success call the ExportCsv FileResult action where I can use the session variable.

So ajax:

```
 $('#masterForm').submit(function (ev) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Analytics/FieldQueryResult',
        data: $('#masterForm').serialize(),
        success: function (data) { 
            if (data.model.ExportCsv === true) {
                window.location.href = 'ExportCsv';                  
            }
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult FieldQueryResult(QueryInput input, bool exportCsv)
{
 //build my csv string, sb
  this.Session["fileString"] = sb.ToString();
 ...
 }
```

Then on ajax success, the ExportCsv Fileresult method is called and the csv string retrieved fro session object

```
public FileResult ExportCsv()
    {
        var fileString = this.Session["fileString"].ToString();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[] { };
        bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileString);
        return File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "report.csv");
    }
```

And the file save dialog pops up with the csv to save. :)